# how to check the type of a variable in swift

Tags: swift

I want to know what the type is of a AnyObject variable that i initialise later.
For example:

```
var test: AnyObject

test = 12.2
```

I cant figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with the `is` operator.
Example code:

```
var test: AnyObject

test = 12.2

if test is Double {
    println("Double type")
} else if test is Int {
    println("Int type")
} else if test is Float {
    println("Float type")
} else {
    println("Unkown type")
}
```

According to Apple docs:

> Checking Type
>
> Use the type check operator (is) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns true if
>   the instance is of that subclass type and false if it is not.